# defining half of the module in one package and other half in another in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I want to do this.

In package 1

```
xyz
  __init__.py 
  abc 
     __init__.py
```

In package 2

```
xyz 
   efg
      __init__.py
```

to get an overall view with both combined. This is possible to do in java even though the classes are in separate jars. Is this something I can do in Python even if I have 2 separate eggs for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkgutil.extend_path()` can be used to merge multiple packages found on `sys.path` together. Note that each must be a proper package on its own.

```
## In xyz/__init__.py:

import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: hmm. so does that mean I need to add multiple __init__.py files for xyz everywhere? also will i have to put the pkgutil thing in every __init__.py?

Comment: You need one per. But they can be empty. Only the first one in `sys.path` should need the call.

Comment: ok, if I can't control which one is the first one on sys path, then I should add it everywhere right?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, it might cause an infinite loop. But you'll be able to tell very quickly if there's a problem.

Comment: ok one more question, will it execute both the __init__.py files and merge them or just one?

Comment: I don't know. I would think that it would execute both of them, but I have no proof.